# Writing XSD schema: if one field contains "A", then other field should not contain "B". How?

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, schema

A simple scenario: if one field contains "A", then the other field should not contain "B". How to write a XSD schema for it.
Example:

```
<root>
<field_1>A</field_1>
<field_2>B</field_2>
</root>
```

How to write an XSD schema that imposes restriction on the value of an element, depending on the value of another element?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in XML Schema 1.0 - you need to look elsewhere, like at [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com) or [Relax NG](http://www.relaxng.org) for those kinds of validations.

Comment: Because it is designed for linear-time front-to-back validation, so it can be used with streams. The only thing that violates that are the key/keyref rules, and these usually need to be activated separately for that reason.